# Ordering Algorithm in R -- Syntax Problems?

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, logical-operators

I'm trying to implement an ordering algorithm based on dates of events in a data frame.  The dates are strings of the form `07/10/1989 07:59` and I went through a process of extracting their numeric values and eventually got an array with 5 columns with rows of the form `7 10 89 7 59`.

Here's the problem: I'm trying to sort the original data frame using this array of numeric values with for loops and if statements:

```
 for (i in 1:(L-1)){
  for (j in (i+1):L){
    if (Dates_Num[i,3] > Dates_Num[j,3]) {
      a    <- V[i]
      V[i] <- V[j]
      V[j] <- a
    }
    else if(match(Dates_Num[i,3], Dates_Num[j,3], nomatch = F) == 1) {
      if (Dates_Num[i,1] > Dates_Num[j,1]) {
        a    <- V[i]
        V[i] <- V[j]
        V[j] <- a ...
```

and there are more nestings of exactly the same form.  The algorithm executes, and there's no loss of information, but it doesn't order the data frame by dates.  For reference `Dates_Num` is my 5-column array of numeric dates, and initially `V = 1:L` where `L` is the number of rows in the data frame.  I've tried on simple toy examples that if I give `V` the right permutation then `Dates_Num[V,]` should hopefully have the correct permutation, and same with the data frame.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there some kind of syntax I got wrong?

Comment: Why you want to do this? R has the `order` and `sort` function to do this task.

Comment: This seems like a very odd way to do things. Why not just convert the date time values to proper Date/POSIXct values in R and use the standard sorting functions? It would help to give some sample input and desired output to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @nicola Does it work on strings or do I need to convert the dates into integers?

Comment: If `dates` is your vector with the dates, just try `sort(as.POSIXct(dates,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))` (assuming that the first digits are the months).